# Inheritance in JPA: How to insert with same ID

Tags: java, jpa

I have a base class Person and 3 classes, which inherits from Person. here are some short snippets:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model{

    // ATTRIBUTES
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
    protected String firstName;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
    protected String lastName;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
    protected String password;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(50) not null")
    protected String eMail;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Boss extends Person {

    // ATTRIBUTES
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String dtype;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "boss")
    private List<Employee> listEmployee;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Employee extends Person {

    // ATTRIBUTES
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String dtype;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "Varchar(20)")
    private String position;
    @ManyToOne
    private Boss boss;
```

Now I want to store an Employee, a Boss and then an Employee again:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(...);
Person p1 = new Person(e1);
Boss b = new Boss(...);
Person p2 = new Person(b);
Employee e2 = new Employee(...);
Person p3 = new Person(e2);
e1.save();
p1.save();
b.save();
p2.save();
e2.save();
p3.save();
```

This will produce 2 Entries in Employee with id 1 and 2, 1 entry in boss with id 1 and 3 entries in Person with id 1,2 and 3. 
e1 has id 1 in Employee and id 1 in Person, boss has id 1 in Boss and id 2 in Person and e2 has id 2 in Employee and id 3 in Person.

Is it possible to insert an Employee, which has the same id in Employee and Person without using a global counter in my programm?

Thank you

Patrik

Answer (score 0):

You do no need to create and persist instance of Person - in fact Person should probably be an abstract class. Given the correct mappings (which you don't currently have) all you should need is the following:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(...);
Boss b = new Boss(...);
Employee e2 = new Employee(...);

e1.save();
b.save();
e2.save();
```

In your mappings remove `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`form Boss and Employee and add it to the person class.

Additionally you do not need a Discrimator for TABLE_PER_CLASS so you can remove the following from Boss and Employee:

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false) private String dtype;
```